# Set DateTimePicker default to today in C# WinForms

Tags: c#, datetimepicker

How can I set the default value of a `DateTimePicker` to today (the day when I run the app, not the day I create the form)?

I am searching for a designer way to do it. I really do not want to mess with `Form.designer.cs` (`InitializeComponenet()`).

Comment: `dateTimePicker1.Value = DateTime.Now;`?

Comment: what's difference between 'runtime and the development'

Comment: Just add it in your form's constructor, don't try to overcomplicate things

Comment: @Pikoh - could you demonstrate how?

Comment: @Sipo see my answer

Comment: Why all the downvotes?!

Comment: What do you mean by not the day I create the form? DateTime.Now or .UtcNow will always pick the datetime of runtime....

Comment: @Sipo if you don't know how to work with a form's constructor you should be looking for a .NET tutorial first, then a Windows Forms tutorial. The downvotes are because you didn't even try to find out how to set a control's value before asking for others to do it for you. SO is a Q&A site, not a discussion forum. Check the help article [How to aks a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I know how to work with them. I just didn't understand the English.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I know how to set control's value and that `DateTime.Now` returns the current date. I just didn't use `DateTimePicker` in my life. I wanted to ask how to set the default value of it to today *without* writing code, but using the VS designer, but I failed to express that due to my bad English. I thought the question was clear, but as soon as I understood it wasn't, I edited my question.

Comment: @Sipo this has nothing to do with DateTimePicker. Setting initial values to controls, binding them to data,  works the same for all of them.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, true. You could set the default value of all of them using the designer. And you could do that is the designer. My question was if the designer allows you more flexibility than writing an hard-coded date as default. And the answer is YES.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just add the initialization of the `DateTimePicker` in your form's constructor:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    dateTimePicker1.Value = DateTime.Now;
}
```

You could also create a new control inheriting DateTimePicker and put the initialization there, but i don't think it's worth the job

Comment: Now I see what you meant. Isn't there a way to do it with the VS designer? This seems to be an obvious option, and it's really weird that I need to actually write a line down for it.

Comment: Well...I think that `DateTimePicker` is created with the system time by default. So I don't know exactly what you want

Comment: Well, I didn't know that. If the default is already the system time, why did you suggest I add this line?

Comment: @Sipo it's not weird and there's no reason to do it in the designer. The designer is for *designing* things. There are specific methods that are called when a form is created, loaded or displayed where you can specify what values will be displayed.

Comment: Because you asked? Sometimes people ask things trying to know something different. In your case, maybe you wanted to get the actual date but changing the time, or as in the other answer, the date plus one day. That's why

Comment: @Pikoh - thanks. I just didn't know that the default is the system date. I did change the date and the value of the `DateTimePicker` changed as well. Sorry for not being clear.

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos - I disagree. According to you, the designer shouldn't have a `MaxDate`, `MinDate`, `Modifiers`, `TabIndex`, `Tag`, `Value` and others, because they are not about design. I was just thinking that maybe the `Value` property could contain a ComboBox with options like "today", and "custom" for more flexibility. As @Pikoh explained, it isn't the case not because it's not the designer job, but because the default is already as "Today".

Comment: @Sipo the designer has **none** of these properties. These are properties of the control classes. The designer has absolutely no knowledge of specific controls. Otherwise you wouldn't be able to create custom controls or use third-party controls. The designer just displays all  class properties that have specific attributes. If you are confused about this you need to search for a tutorial course.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos When I talk about the designer I mean the Properties panel. I needed to know if there is a nice way for setting the value for today using this panel. A property that works similar to what I want is `Format`. You could choose between `Long`, `Short`, `Time` and `Custom`. IF you choose `Custom` you can set `CustomFormat` to whatever you want. Similarly, I thought there is an option for `DateTimePicker`'s value to be a `Today` and `Custom` or something like that. There isn't such an option because the default is already the system date, not because it's not the designer job.

Answer (score 1):

Just need to set the value property in a convenient place (such as InitializeComponent()):

```
dateTimePicker1.Value = DateTime.Today;
```

Comment: Why `AddDays(-1);`?

Comment: that's just an example instead of `DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1)` put whatever requiremens

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have clarified my question. Please review it.